# Compress Zip to 7zip

Tags: linux, bash, zip, conversion, 7z

I would like a shell (or other terminal based) script to convert zip files to 7z format.
Some zip files contain folders with more zip files in them. This needs to work recursively since there are zip files in folders inside the origin zip files. Hope this makes sense.

I am using linux not windows.

Regards,
Brian

Comment: What have you tried? What happened when you tried that? How did that differ from what you wanted/expected to happen?